# Partition pruning based on check constraint not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-partitioning, postgresql-performance

Why is the table "events_201504" included in the query plan below? Based on my query and the check constraint on that table I would expect the query planner to be able to prune it entirely:

```
database=# \d events_201504
                                   Table "public.events_201504"
    Column     |            Type             |                           Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id            | bigint                      | not null default nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "events_201504_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "events_201504_created_at" btree (created_at)
Check constraints:
    "events_201504_created_at_check" CHECK (created_at >= '2015-04-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND created_at <= '2015-04-30 23:59:59.999999'::timestamp without time zone)
Inherits: events
```

Time and configuration:

```
database=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2015-05-25 16:49:20.037815-05

database=# show constraint_exclusion;
 constraint_exclusion
----------------------
 on
```

The query plan:

```
database=# explain select count(1) from events where created_at > now() - '1 hour'::interval;
                                                                QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=3479.86..3479.87 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..3327.90 rows=60784 width=0)
         ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=0)
               Filter: (created_at > (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))
         ->  Index Only Scan using events_201504_created_at on events_201504  (cost=0.57..4.59 rows=1 width=0)
               Index Cond: (created_at > (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))
         ->  Index Only Scan using events_201505_created_at on events_201505  (cost=0.57..3245.29 rows=60765 width=0)
               Index Cond: (created_at > (now() - '01:00:00'::interval))
```

Comment: Try executing  now() - '1 hour'::interval; ,and put that value in place of  now() - '1 hour'::interval;. It should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your column `created_at` is of type `timestamp without time zone`.

But `now()` returns `timestamp with time zone`. The expression `now() - '1 hour'::interval` is being coerced to `timestamp [without time zone]`, which carries **two problems**:

**1.)** You did not ask for this, but the expression is unreliable. Its result depends on the current time zone setting of the session the query is being executed in. Details here:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

To make the expression clear, you could use:

```
now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' -- your time zone here
```

Or just [(read the manual here)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

```
LOCALTIMESTAMP  -- explicitly take the local time
```

I would consider working with `timestamptz` instead.
Neither solves your second problem:

**2.) Answer to your question.** Constraint exclusion does not work. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CAVEATS)

> The following caveats apply to constraint exclusion:
>
> - [...]
> - Constraint exclusion only works when the query's `WHERE` clause contains constants (or externally supplied parameters). For example, a
>   comparison against a **non-immutable function such as
>   `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` cannot be optimized**, since the planner cannot know
>   which partition the function value might fall into at run time.

Bold emphasis mine.

`now()` is the Postgres implementation of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. As you can see in the system catalog, it is only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`:

```
SELECT proname, provolatile FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'now';

proname | provolatile
--------+------------
now     | s              -- meaning: STABLE
```

#### Solutions

**1.)** You can overcome the limitation by providing a constant in the `WHERE` condition (which is always "immutable"):

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM events
WHERE created_at > '2015-05-25 15:49:20.037815'::timestamp;  -- from your example
```

**2.)** Or by "faking" an immutable function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_now_immutable()
  RETURNS timestamp
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';  -- your time zone here
$func$;
```

And then:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM events
WHERE created_at > f_now_immutable() - interval '1 hour';
```

Be careful how you use this though: while `now()` is `STABLE` (does not change for the duration of a transaction), it *does* change between transactions, so take care not to use this in prepared statements (except as parameter value) or indexes or anything where it might bite you.

**3.)** Or you can add seemingly redundant constant `WHERE` clauses to your current query that match the constraint on your partition:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   events
WHERE  created_at > now() - '1 hour'::interval
AND    created_at >= '2015-04-01 00:00:00'::timestamp
AND    created_at <= '2015-04-30 23:59:59.999999'::timestamp;
```

Just make sure yourself that `now() - '1 hour'::interval` falls into the right partition or you get no results, obviously.

Aside: I would rather use this expression in `CHECK` constraints and query. Easier to handle and does the same:

```
       created_at >= '2015-04-01'::timestamp
AND    created_at <  '2015-05-01'::timestamp
```